# Simplifying setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

To make my code more readable and simpler I was breaking my head over this piece of code:

```
var refresh = setInterval(datumTijd, 1000);

function datumTijd() {
  document.getElementById("tijd1").innerHTML = tijd();
  document.getElementById("tijd2").innerHTML = tijd();
}

function tijd(){
  var d1 = new Date(),
      minutes = d1.getMinutes().toString().length == 1 ? '0'+d1.getMinutes() : d1.getMinutes(),
      hours = d1.getHours().toString().length == 1 ? '0'+d1.getHours() : d1.getHours();
  return hours+ ':' +minutes;
}
```

Although this does work, I have the feeling that there is one function too many, which is the `document.getElementById` - bit where I update two different `<div>`s. I just couldn't find a way to get rid of this part as I was getting stuck because of that `return` code.

My try:

```
var refresh = setInterval(tijd, 1000);

function tijd(){
  var d1 = new Date(),
      minutes = d1.getMinutes().toString().length == 1 ? '0'+d1.getMinutes() : d1.getMinutes(),
      hours = d1.getHours().toString().length == 1 ? '0'+d1.getHours() : d1.getHours();
  return hours+ ':' +minutes;
  document.getElementById("tijd1").innerHTML = d1;
}
```

But nothing comes back :(

Comment: When you execute `return`, it ends the function. Change that to a variable assignment, and then put it in the `innerHTML`.

Comment: I actually think your 2 functions make sense, you could even make a 3th function that sets the inner html of an element ;)

Comment: Not exactly related, but those ternary operators look awful. You could add the leading zero with `substr` instead, like `hours = ('0' + d1.getHours()).substr(-2);`

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for that explanation on the  `return`. @Teemu Thanks for your heads up on this. I am just starting to learn some js here and there so I am already surprised that I was actually quite on track with what I have. I will take your comment on-board!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning from the function before you put anything into the `innerHTML`. And you're also putting the wrong thing in the `innerHTML`.

```
function tijd(){
  var d1 = new Date(),
      minutes = d1.getMinutes().toString().length == 1 ? '0'+d1.getMinutes() : d1.getMinutes(),
      hours = d1.getHours().toString().length == 1 ? '0'+d1.getHours() : d1.getHours(),
      time = hours+ ':' +minutes;
  document.getElementById("tijd1").innerHTML = time;
  document.getElementById("tijd2").innerHTML = time;
}
```

I don't really see a problem with separating the function that creates the time string with the one that puts it in innerHTML, as in your original code. You may have other places where you need to get the time, so it's worthwhile separating it into its own function. The only change I'd make to your original code is to use a variable instead of calling the function twice:

```
function datumTijd() {
  var time = tijd();
  document.getElementById("tijd1").innerHTML = time;
  document.getElementById("tijd2").innerHTML = time;
}
```

You also have the question tagged with jQuery, so you could simplify the assignments with:

```
function datumTijd() {
    $("#tijd1, #tijd2").text(tijd());
}
```

Comment: It could always use an extra method called `function setHtml(selector, value) { (document.querySelectorAll(selector) || []).forEach(function(item) { item.innerHTML = value; }); }` or some simpler form of this action ;) (forEach when `'use strict'` is set somewhere ofcourse :D)

Comment: Thanks for your edit Barmar, I was actually just about to hit google for that part but no need now!